# How to know if ImageSource is a jpg or png file

Tags: angular, nativescript

My application allows users to upload profile picture from the app to my server. It works great for .png files but it doesn't work for .jpg files.

What I do:

1. use ImagePicker to allow user to select image(s).
2. display available images to user.
3. store selected image locally when user taps save
4. upload image in the cloud

The problem is at step 3, I don't know how to know if file should be saved as png or jpg.

```js
    startSelection(context: ImagePicker) {
        context
            .authorize()
            .then(() => {
                return context.present();
            })
            .then(selection => {
                selection.forEach(selectedItem => {
                    ImageSource.fromAsset(selectedItem).then(imageSource => {
                        this.imageUrls.push(imageSource);
                        this.selectedUrlIndex = this.imageUrls.length - 1;
                    });
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                // ...
            });
    }
```

```js
    onSave(): void {
        const folder = fs.knownFolders.documents();
        const path = fs.path.join(folder.path, 'avatar.png');
        const saved = this.getSelectedAvatar().saveToFile(path, 'png');

        this.userService
            .sendImages(path)
            .then(() => {
                // ...
            });
    }
```

My issue is at this line `this.getSelectedAvatar().saveToFile(path, 'png');`, getSelectedAvatar returns an [ImageSource](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource)

Comment: Can you explain why this a problem? Is there any error message given? Why not use the file extension given in the input file?

Comment: Because ImagePicker does not return the file extension, only ImageAsset... So I don't know how to have the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the docs for the "saveToFile" method](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource), I don't think it matters what it was. You could try picking a jpeg and seeing if it saves fine as a png (or visa versa).

(update)
Since [this comment in the source code](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/image-asset/image-asset.d.ts#L11) says the ImageSource can be either a `UIImage for iOS and android.graphics.Bitmap for Android`, you *should* be able to save in whatever format you prefer regardless of input. You may also be able to use the `ios` or `android` field from the `ImageSource` to get more info about the image [(see this link)](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/image-source/image-source.d.ts#L26-L34).

Comment: (I'm not the one who downvoted you) If it worked out of the box I wouldn't be here. I can upload png right now, If I switch 'png' to 'jpg', I can upload it as jpg, but I have no way to make this work for both formats, meaning that the saveToFile probably don't create a png if you give it a jpg.

Comment: Ah, I understand where you are a little better now- Updated the answer after some source digging.

Comment: As @OneLunchMan mentioned, it's upto you to choose a format while calling `saveToFile`. For photos, JPEG is mostly preferred as it can be smaller in size.

Comment: Well, it was my fault, I set a limit to 500kb for all pictures. I pick one picture, the file manager says it has a size of 300kb in jpg, once it is written into png it does 600kb (but I don't know because NativeScript can't tell size) then it's sent to the server which throws an error. I didn't realize size could change that much. It looks like saveToFile does the job correctly.